# Inside a bash script, how to get PID from a program executed when using the eval command?

Tags: bash, unix, process, eval, pid

I have commands in a bash script that are similar to this:

```
eval "( java -classpath ./ $classname ${arguments[@]} $redirection_options $file )" &
pid=$!
```

However if I do a `ps $pid` it shows the main script process instead of the process of the java program.

It obtains the correct process when I omit the eval, but in order to get some of the complicated arguments to work correctly I need to use it.

Any idea of how I can get the PID of the java program when it's executed within an eval command?

Comment: **TL;DR:** use `$!` after your line with the ampersand `&` (such as `myprogram &`)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your ampersand is backgrounding the `eval` line, causing the (top-level) shell to fork a child, the child shell to `eval` the string and in turn run your java program as a grandchild of the top-level shell.  So, `$!` reports the pid of the child shell, which is the most recently backgrounded command.

Instead move the backgrounding inside your eval:

```
eval "(java ...) &"
pid=$!
```

As long as the parenthetical doesn't get complicated enough to become a *subshell*, the above will work.

Comment: Yes, this is it :) `EXPR="java -jar test.jar &"; eval $EXPR; echo $!` should do

Comment: FYI: I noticed this works from a terminal but if you have a script with an icon on the desktop, it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure to add `"` double quotes around the expression being evaluated, and also make sure to add the `&` inside those double quotes, just before the final double quote.